# Drawing entity relationship diagrams -ERD

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I need to draw entity relationship diagrams for https://askubuntu.com/.
but I can't see entities and entities set.
is there anyone who can help?

I need basic RDBM for askubuntu pls ?

Comment: I think this is not really a specific question per se, but rather, you are being asked to determine what could possibly be the ERD diagram for the website? In that case, you need to brush up on designing database schema and start mapping out the info you see on that website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at that website will tell me that it would have the following tables:

```
Questions
QuestionTags
Tags
Answers
QuestionViews
Users
```

**Question Table**

```
QuestionId
QuestionText
```

**Tags Table**

```
TagId
TagName
```

**QuestionTags Table**
Note: This table will have a relationship to the Questions and Tags table.

```
QuestionTagsId
QuestionId
TagId
```

**Answers Table**

```
AnswerId
QuestionId
UserId
AnswerDate
```

**Users Table**

```
UserId
UserName
```

**QuestionViews Table**

```
QuestionViewId
ViewDate
```

Generally, this is a very basic database table definition to contain the information for the website you provided. You would need to define the proper relationships, column types and other constraints.

I provided this to provide you some headstart on where to look for next.

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for giving me a starting point and helping me to imagine

Comment: If this helped you in any form get started, you could probably mark this as an answer as it can also help other get to a starting point.

Comment: how can I do what you say?

Comment: it took me a long time to find :) 
I probably handled

ty for hint .really I'm grateful